# How to close a tab that has a scammer website loaded ("This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave")?

Tags: firefox

A website displays "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." in Firefox whenever I try to close the tab

Is there a way for me to close the tab without having to restart Firefox?

I have AdBlock loaded. Maybe I can do something from the developer console.

Comment: Can you use Task Manager to end the task under the Applications tab?

Comment: Can't you just click "leave anyway"?

Comment: @MarkHenderson: It will pop up the message again immediately thereafter.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81: I dont want to restart firefox

Comment: I would kill Firefox, then hope it asks me if I want to recover my session when I relaunch it. I know it gives you the option to only reopen certain tabs when you relaunch after a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't mention the site you're having problem with, try these yourself:

1. Does it only happen with Firefox? not with other browsers ? (probably all browsers will show same behavior)
2. When you get the prompt ( usually, when you are filling a form, or writing something to post), do you get two options : Leave Page and Stay On Page ? If you get, then click Leave 
   Page
3. If you don't get such options, then disabling JavaScript is a solution, but rather than doing it, open the site from a script blocking proxy, like [www.ninjacloak.com](http://www.ninjacloak.com)

Comment: I won't publish the URL because I don't want others to click it. 1. It will probably cause other browsers to behave similarly. 2. I already mentioned that this is a scammer website and clicking 'Leave Page' will only trigger the same message. 3. Disabling Javascript will probably not remove the script that's currently causing the message in main memory to be stopped, or not? I don't want to visit the website any more, I just want to leave it.

Comment: did try disabling JavaScript? AFAIK these alerts are powered by JavaScript.

Comment: Wow, I just did that in about:config and it worked; I didn't have to restart firefox. Afterwards, I just toggeled it back. Thank you

Comment: thats what i said in point #3 . open the site from a proxy that disables all JavaScript, like www.ninjacloak.com, which requires fewer clicks and less time than about:config

Comment: The site was already open in a regular tab. The issue was just getting away from it or closing it. If I go to this proxy site (in another tab), open the malicious website from the proxy, then the original tab is still open.

Answer (score 2):

Nuke it from orbit, its the only way to be sure.

Actually... quite literally. I'd probably kill the browser process, restart the browser, clear the caches, delete it from history... etc. There's ways to make browser windows that are resilient to most other ways of closing a window.

Comment: Then block the site permenently.

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor on top of (or over) the window.

Hold down the **ALT** key and press and release **F4**

If it keeps coming back after that maybe MalwareBytes and Another AV product.